# Java Swagger (Springfox) annotations for streaming multipart file upload

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

We are using spring controllers to handle file uploads:

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/scan", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ScanResult scan(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, FileUploadException {
    return scanService.scanFile(parseMultipart(request));
}
```

But we are not using any multipart resolver, we are streaming the files from the servlet request input stream. We need to start processing the file immediately for performance reasons.

When doing this this way, we can't seem to use the typical detection/configuration for multipart files. I know Springfox (which we use to generate our swagger docs) will generate the appropriate swagger controls if it sees a MultipartFile as a controller parameter, which will not be the case for us.

Are there any other config options available to hint to springfox that we want a file upload here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found my answer here: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1285

The following implicit params give me what I need:

```
@ApiImplicitParams (value = {
    @ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "file", name = "file", required = true,paramType = "form")}
@RequestMapping(value = "/scan", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ScanResult scan(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, FileUploadException {
    return scanService.scanFile(parseMultipart(request));
}
```

This adds a simple file picker to the API. To make things more confusing, turns out this functionality was broken in Springfox 2.4 - the version I was using. Adding that annotation and updating versions was all I needed to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this.  And for any future onlookers, Springfox 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT breaks this functionality, though it works in 2.6.0.

Answer (score 8):

Regarding breaking changes in Springfox v2.7.0:

You need to use `dataType = "__file"` instead of `file` as commented in https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1285

Comment: Thank you this helped me! I encountered this issue in Springfox 2.9.2

Answer (score 0):

That's right
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44385675/3810914

In Controller It should be:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Upload file", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request")
    })
    @ApiImplicitParams (value = {
            @ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "__file", name = "fileData", required = true,paramType = "form")})
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFileSimple(UploadFile form) {

        // Create folder to save file if not exist
        File uploadDir = new File(UPLOAD_DIR);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
            uploadDir.mkdirs();
        }

        MultipartFile fileData = form.getFileData();
        String name = fileData.getOriginalFilename();
        if (name != null && name.length() > 0) {
            try {
                // Create file
                File serverFile = new File(UPLOAD_DIR + "/" + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(fileData.getBytes());
                stream.close();
                return ResponseEntity.ok("/file/" + name);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error when uploading");
            }
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Bad request");
    }
```

And In Model:

```
package com.xxx.xxx.request;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UploadFile {
    private MultipartFile fileData;
}
```

[image]